# Qt native UI libraries?

Tags: qt

I'm new to QT. I'm starting to use QT Creator. Is there a way of creating native OS UIs with QT? Are there any Windows and OS X UI libraries or visual designers?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a bit strange. Qt is a cross-platform library. It has its own GUI technology that defaults to looking like the native GUI toolkit. What exactly are you after?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. I want a way to create native GUI elements: main menu with drop-down options, buttons, dialogs, etc. So far I've been using QML to define elements manualy with blocks like Rectangle and so on. The best would be a visual designer where you can drag-n-drop elements onto app window/canvas.

Comment: Did you go through any of the Qt (including designer) examples/tutorials/docs?

Comment: Qt Creator is an IDE with support for visual design of QWidget and QML-based user interfaces. You can use it to create native applications that don't use Qt, but you'll need to use external tools to edit the interface definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want native OS UIs as in something that looks like Windows on Windows and something that looks like OS X on OS X, you should create a "Qt Designer Form Class" in Qt Creator.

This will give you a .cpp, a .h and a .ui file. The UI designer for this .ui file will automatically open.

You can also create the .ui file only, by selecting "Qt Designer Form", but then you have to integrate the .ui file (or rather the resulting class generated by Qt) into your code yourself.

Comment: Tx, Tim, this makes sense. But... can you give more detailed example of what I should do or a link to a manual for this exact action?

Comment: You'd best click the "Help" button on the left-hand side panel in Qt Creator and look for the "Creating a Qt Widget Based Application" topic in the "Getting Started" section